# Firestore - How can I make a query by two map fields and orderBy another?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I need to query a list of documents by two different map fields(localities and servicesTypes) and order by a createdAt field.
[image: the image shows the two map fields]

I am trying to make that query and it looks like this:

```
var query = firestore
      .collection("services")
      .where(`localities.${locationId}`, "==", true);
    servicesTypes.map((serviceType) => {
      query = query.where(`servicesTypes.${serviceType}`, "==", true);
    });
    query = query.orderBy("createdAt");
    return query.get();
```

The problem is that I get a firebase error that says that I need to index every locationId, but this is not good because I have a lot of localities and they will be more in the future.

Just to say, I have tried another combination of the structure with 'array-contains' and the problem was that I need to filter by two 'array-contains' and it is not supported by firestore.

I wonder to ask if someone can help me to figure out a solution to make that query. I am also open to change the structure of the fields in order to get the query done. Thanks!

Comment: Just a note: It's semantically more correct to `reduce` the `serviceTypes` into the query, rather than to `map` them. `reduce` takes the values of the array and _reduces_ them to a single output; `map` takes the values and _maps_ them to new values in another array.

Comment: Your query looks fine to me [according to the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#compound_queries) - strictly equality clauses don't require indexing. Have you tried removing the `orderBy` clause? The documentation doesn't specify that `orderBy` would require an index, but that's the only clause that isn't equality.

Comment: @j1mbl3s You can be right, but this will not solve the problem, right?

Comment: @j1mbl3s If I remove the orderBy it works perfectly, but I need the orderBy...

Comment: Then, that is the issue with your provided query. If you need the results ordered, but the `orderBy` is giving you problems, then you can always sort the result set on the client. E.g. `querySnapshot.docs.sort((doc1, doc2) => { const createdAt1 = doc1.get('createdAt'), createdAt2 = doc2.get('createdAt'); return createdAt1 > createdAt2 ? 1 : createdAt1 < createdAt2 ? -1 : 0; });`

Comment: The Firebase team should probably update the documentation to provide details on when [`orderBy`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/order-limit-data) requires indexing.

Comment: I can definitely do this, but the reason why I am doing that like this I because after that, I want to complete the query adding pagination with .limit() and .startAfter(). In order to do that I need the ordered data from firestore and not from the client...

Comment: I'd recommend following up with the Firebase team about this, as per the documentation you should be able to `orderBy` without requiring an index. You can join their community slack channel [here](http://firebase.community/)

Comment: Another option is to keep all of the `locationId`s and `serviceId`s in a single array, specifying which items are location vs. service with a control character (e.g. `locationId<control>`, `<control>serviceId`). Then you could use `array-contains` as a filter clause, however you would be limited to 10 array-containing items (per your example, 9 `serviceIds`). Similarly, you could just keep `serviceId`s in an array, since that is the only one being queried as an array-like (multiple services per query)

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I hope they can help